# C get all references to object?

Tags: c, object, pointers, memory-management, struct

If I have an object `atype obj` where `atype` is defined like `typedef struct myType {...} * atype`, is there any way I can get all the references to `obj`, or at least how many there are?

#### Something like:

```
atype obj;
... // Allocate

aStruct a;
a.obj = obj;

aStruct b;
b.obj = obj;

int refs = get_references(obj); // refs should now = 2
```

Any ideas? Workarounds and alternative methods welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no implicit way. But you could implement a `ref` function that automatically increases a counter, and an `unref` function to decrement it.

```
a.obj = ref(obj);

/* ... */
a.obj = something_else;
unref(obj);
```

And that counter can be something external to any of the `struct`s. For example, you could use a hash table to keep track of pointer - counter relationships.

#### EDIT

You can also look into [`gobject`](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) which provides this via `g_object_ref` / `g_object_unref`.

Comment: I'm already using an ref/unref counter, I was just thinking that automatically getting rid of objects that aren't referenced anywhere would be convenient. Thanks for the link, though ;)